# Trying to setup HTTP2 on Apache

Tags: apache-2.4

I've installed apache 2.4.18 from

`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade`

in ssl.conf I deactivated SSLv2 and SSLv2 and left all enabled:

`SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384$
 SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3`

added in vhost file under https section:

`Protocols h2 http/1.1`

After restarting apache I get in error log that mod_http2 had been initialised without any other errors

`[Fri Jan 29 20:31:58.829149 2016] [http2:info] [pid 20952] mod_http2 (v1.0.11, nghttp2 1.6.0), initializing...`

Accessing the website (https) will use http/1.1 on both Chrome and Safari. On Safari there's also an Upgrade header with h2 value.

Any tips on how to make the site use http2, I'm burned out.

Comment: Seems I made it work 4 hours but on Chrome and Safari on OSX El Capitan it still shows http/1.1. On windows shows h2 though

Comment: Possibly due to Avast? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789858/http-2-support-in-chrome-45-0-2454-101-on-mac-os-10-9-5

Comment: @BazzaDP Ouch, that hurts! I've spent 6 hours troubleshooting this and yes, it was Avast. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in comments: turn off Avast https monitoring.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789858/http-2-support-in-chrome-45-0-2454-101-on-mac-os-10-9-5

I hate it when Antivirus software MITM https connections and cause more hassle than they save!