# Nginx ssl http/2 chrome doesnt work

Tags: nginx, chrome, http2

https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test says:

```
HTTP/2 Test Result
Yeah! domain.com supports HTTP/2.0.
ALPN supported.
```

In domain config:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
```

NGINX -V from https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/nginx-mainline:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.11.6
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments:
--with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 
--with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx 
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock 
--pid-path=/run/nginx.pid 
--modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi 
--with-debug 
--with-pcre-jit 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_auth_request_module 
--with-http_v2_module 
--with-http_spdy_module 
--with-http_dav_module 
--with-http_slice_module 
--with-threads 
--with-http_addition_module 
--with-http_geoip_module=dynamic 
--with-http_gunzip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module 
--with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic 
--with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_xslt_module=dynamic 
--with-stream=dynamic 
--with-stream_ssl_module 
--with-mail=dynamic 
--with-mail_ssl_module 
--add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-QXPftz/nginx-1.11.6/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam 
--add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-QXPftz/nginx-1.11.6/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module 
--add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-QXPftz/nginx-1.11.6/debian/modules/nginx-echo 
--add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-QXPftz/nginx-1.11.6/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair 
--add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-QXPftz/nginx-1.11.6/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

But I still got a gray icon in Chrome in `SPDY Indicator`

Comment: Are you sure Chrome indicates HTTP/2 with SPDY? SPDY is Google's initial implementation of a protocol that later came to be HTTP/2. Therefore those are different, and for example, nginx dropped SPDY support once HTTP/2 support was implemented.

Comment: Post a link to your site.

Comment: Tero Kilkanen,  `SPDY Indicator` indicates HTTP/2 too with blue arrow

Comment: Anti virus software breaking this? http://serverfault.com/questions/752767/trying-to-setup-http2-on-apache/752786?s=3|2.0603#752786